# Get latest key value pair from Redis in Java Spring

Tags: spring, redis

I have an application on Java Spring that uses Redis fore some caching. Is there a way how to get a key or key-value pair that was added to the Redis last?

I have also 3 different types of values (Entities) that are stored to the Redis. Is there a way how get the latest record of one exact type of "value"?

Is Redis even suitable for such kind of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Redis doesn't have this built-in functionality. You need to do it manually.

Whenever you set a key, you need to set that key name to an another key such as latest:key

```
set entity:1 value:1
set latest:key entity:1
get latest:key
```

You may also use hash to set the latest's key as field and value as hash value.

```
hset latest:key entity:1 value:1
hgetall latest:key
```